# Download an Arq backup on Windows

Tags: backup, amazon-glacier

I was using Arq to backup data to Glacier from my Mac. Now I need to download that data onto a Windows machine since my Mac went kaput :(

Any ideas how to do that? Fastglacier doesn't show the filenames...

Answer (score 0):

Arq stores your data in it's own file format which is [documented here](http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/s3_data_format.txt). You will most likely have to use Arq on another Mac to get the files.